# How to pass element in the converter parameter in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have to pass the element in the converter parameter in UWP as like below WPF code snippet.

```
   <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource captionSummaryRowConverter}, ConverterParameter= {x:Reference Name= dataGrid}}" Foreground="Blue" Background="Yellow" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
   </DataTemplate>
```

Since x:Reference keyword is not available in the Uwp, Is there any possible way to pass the element to converterparameter in uwp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to pass element in the converter parameter in uwp?

Currently, Converter does not support pass element `ConverterParameter`. We often use it to pass `StaticResource`  or string format.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DoubleValue,Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter},ConverterParameter='{}{0:N2}'}"/>
```

**OR**

```
<TextBlock Text="Score : 60" Foreground="{Binding Passed,Converter={StaticResource BoolToValueConverter},ConverterParameter={StaticResource PassedBrush},FallbackValue={StaticResource FailedBrush}}"/>
```

**Update**

You could add the property to the Converter and bind with your root panel, then pass the element name as parameter to the Converter, call FindName method to get the element.

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
 {
     public UIElement UIParameter { get; set; }
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
     {
         var rootGrid = UIParameter as Grid;
         if(parameter != null)
         {
             var ele = rootGrid.FindName(parameter.ToString());

         }

         return value;
     }
 }
```

**Usage**

```
<local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" UIParameter="{x:Bind RootGrid}" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TestBlock" Text="Hello" />
    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, ConverterParameter='TestBlock'}" />
    <ComboBox
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass reference object through the converter parameter? and if Uwp doesn't support how can i pass the element to the converter parameter.

Comment: Could you share more about what feature that you want realize ?

Comment: ConverterParameter= {x:Reference Name= dataGrid} Actually here datagrid is the control. I want to get this data grid in my parameter through which i can access the datagrid.View. I have achieved the same in WPF but i cant achieve in UWP and also i dont have idea how to achieve.

Comment: I used this to make an Converter that converts the bound item to its index in an ItemsControl's Items, e.g. from a ListBox, or ListView  ItemTemplate